# Detect and do action only when closing browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am pretty new to javascript. I want to give some action only when close the browser.
I used below jquery function to give an action when close the browser, but this function gives an action when moving to another page or refresh the page. Can I give an action only when an user clicks the X button or close the browser?

Please Help, thank you..

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function (e){

    return "close window?";

});
```

Comment: I'm affraid it's not possible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3888938/16688813).